# The expandable list view is not expanding the list when clicked. I tried to set the clickable but still clicking on list doesn't expand anything

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, expandablelistview

I used an expandable list view in the main layout and then used other two layout. The list_parent includes textfield, so clicking on that textfield it should expand to show the third layout which is the list_child and it also contain a text view.

But the problem is that whenever I click on those texts on the expandable list view in activity_main it doesn't expand. I also tried to set the clickable as true in activity_main and added **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** in the ExpandableListView but it's still not expanding on click.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.calcounterapplication.demoexlist;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    List<String> langs;
    Map<String, List<String>> topics;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
         fillData();

         listAdapter = new MyExListAdapter(this,langs,topics);
         expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void fillData()
    {
        langs = new ArrayList<>();
        topics = new HashMap<>();

        langs.add("Java");
        langs.add("C");

        List<String> java = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();

        java.add("Super");
        java.add("Encapsulation");
        java.add("Methods");

        c.add("Procedure");
        c.add("Pointers");
        c.add("Array");

        topics.put(langs.get(0),java);
        topics.put(langs.get(1),c);

    }
}
```

MyExListAdapter.java

```
package com.calcounterapplication.demoexlist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyExListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
Context context;
List<String> langs;
Map<String, List<String>> topics;

public MyExListAdapter(Context context, List<String> langs, Map<String, List<String>> topics) {
this.context = context;
this.langs = langs;
this.topics = topics;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return langs.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return topics.get(langs.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return langs.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return topics.get(langs.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)                     {

String lang = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if(convertView == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent,null);
}

TextView txtParent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtParent);
txtParent.setText(lang);

return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View     convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

String topic = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

if(convertView == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child,null);
}

TextView txtChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtChild);
txtChild.setText(topic);

return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_parent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtParent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Large Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

list_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/txtChild"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```